# Why can't I access a variable from my header.php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my header.php  I have a variable called $navigation with a class assigned to it .. `$navigation = $this->nav_class = new \navigation_menu\Navigation();`

When I access the variable $navigation on  index.php , it throws an error saying  undefined variable "$navigation "

But when I instantiate it directly on the index.php it works.

I tried passing the $navigation variable  through the  method name "index", on the controller page and it works well ...

```
public function index()


{

        $data['title'] = "Welcome";

        $data['navigation'] = new \navigation_menu\Navigation();


        $this->load->view('public/includes/header.php', $data);
        $this->load->view('index', $data);
        $this->load->view('public/includes/footer.php');
}
```

That works fine. But the problem is that when I will be needing to use the class for multiple methods. I don't want to instantiate a new object for every method

So that leads me to the next thing  __construct(). But when I did a construct I get this message..

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: PublicPage::$load

Filename: controllers/PublicPage.php
```

Sooo. I guess my only option is to define a new method in the PublicPage.php(controller page) called navigation and return the class... here is what I did

```
private function navigation (){
        return $nav = new \navigation_menu\Navigation();
    }


    public function index()
    {

        $data['title'] = "Welcome";

        $data['navigation'] = $this->navigation();
        $this->load->view('public/includes/header.php', $data);
        $this->load->view('index', $data);
        $this->load->view('public/includes/footer.php');

    }
```

That worked well.  But now I have two questions that doesn't make sense

1. Why can't I access a variable from the header.php on index.php?
2. Why doesn't __construct() work on controllers?

Any help would be really appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$data` variable everywhere, but it's out of scope!
One solution is to define it global as in:

```
global $data;
```

...in the beginning of **every** method you use or need it.
No need to change any more code, it should work out of the box.

The other solution would be having it as the class/object property, **if you use it in this class/object ONLY** (why storing it outside otherwise?), as in:

```
public $data;
```

and accessing it in all methods like

```
$this->data
```

Comment: Well, it's about object properties. If you need this `$data` only to be used by object's methods, then you better define it as objects property and access by `$this->data`. Here, read in PHP.net manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php